# Проверка пароля на сервере

Tags: php, mysql

Привет.

Очень прошу подскажите. Вот такая таблица

```
$sql_create_table="CREATE TABLE users2 (
  id INT(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  login VARCHAR(50),
  password VARCHAR(32),
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  UNIQUE (login)
);";
```

Вношу данные

```
$quoted_password='f45';
$quoted_username='log77';
$sql_insert_into_login="INSERT INTO `users2` (`login`,`password`) VALUES(
'".$quoted_username."','".md5($quoted_password)."')";
```

Теперь не получается проверить юзера

```
 $log=$_POST['login'];
 $pass=$_POST['pass'];
 $sql_set_session="SELECT * FROM `users2` WHERE `login`='".$log."' AND  password='".md5($pass)."'";
```

Проблема именно в проверке пароля.

Comment: [SQL injection](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0)

Comment: @koza4ok, получите по имени пользователя строку из БД, а проверяйте уже вне её.

Comment: Вот так?
$sql_set_session="SELECT * FROM `users2` WHERE `login`='".$log."'";
$res=mysql_query($sql_set_session);
$obj = mysql_fetch_object($res);
if($obj->password===$pass){
 echo 'true';
 }
Ошибка.

Comment: @koza4ok, Ну принцип да. А какая ошибка?

Comment: просто пусто.Не найден!

Comment: @koza4ok, так быть может не существует логина?:(

Comment: логин есть.Если я запрашивал только эту часть  $sql_set_session="SELECT * FROM `users2` WHERE `login`='".mysql_real_escape_string($log)."'
то все работает.

Comment: @koza4ok, попробуйте добавить else в последнее условие. Посмотрите будет вывод или нет. Ведь вы здесь не делали хэширование md5($pass) и тогда бесполезно проверять эквиваленцию

Comment: @koza4ok echo $sql_set_session что выводит?

Comment: На сервере пароль a4dbd8c75d709fe2c0d94c3eb7817f48

    SELECT * FROM `users2` WHERE `login`='log77' AND password='d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$pswrd = md5($pass);

$sql_set_session = "SELECT * FROM `users2` WHERE `login` = '$log' AND `password` = '$pswrd'";
```

Comment: Да спасибо,иногда помогает переработать все с нуля....сработало
Спасибо всем ,кто пытался мне помочь!